# The change In the HTML Input Form Doesn't Affect the DOM

Tags: html, forms, dom, web-inspector

I need to find out how Ebay does something about it's product forms, so that I can apply it to my application. It's essential for form data security. Here is the thing;

On Ebay, when you click on a product, and where it's atributes like capacity, condition,quantity appear, and (in my case) you change the quantity and add it to your shopping cart, for example when you type
10 as quantity but default value is 1, the DOM doesn't change to 10,
but still, 10 items go to the cart. Also, if you make a change in the
DOM itself via browser inspector (say make it 10), the default number of
1 doesn't change to 10. As a result, the only case of what happening is; you type the quantity, and even though the DOM doesn't change, the application still knows the desired quantity. (Please note that other tags like h3 can be manipulated through the DOM Inspector, namely the changes are applied immediately)

I need help figuring out how this is done. Thank you in advance.

[image: This is how I am able to change the h tag value but not the input tag]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any changes made to `value property` will not be updated to `value attribute` of input.

Any changes made to `value attribute` of the input will be updated to `value property` of input only until `value property` is not dirty (i.e not changed from somewhere else). Once the `value property` of input is dirty any changes made to `value attribute` will not update the `value property` of input.

You can use `Element.value` to set or get the `value property` of input.

You can use `Element.getProperty('value')` to get and `Element.setProperty('value')` to set the `value attribute` of input.

Comment: Okay, but what I need to figure out is how they manage to avoid visually changing the elemnt value from DOM tree we open by right clicking and clicking the "Inspect Element" option. For example I can change the value of sarch bar of stackoverflow that way.  What happens on Ebay is even though you change the value, it visually remains the same on the form, but on here the searchbar input value changes to what I type immediately.

Comment: @JaqenH'gaar Run this `Element.value = 'something'` in console or simply type something in the input manually and then try to change the input value from attribute again in stackoverflow

Comment: I just realized, it's not just initial render, value property follows value attribute until it is dirty, Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. It all makes perfect sense now

Answer (score 1):

As far as I saw, once you change the value in your `input` field manually after the browser loads the page, your change from DOM does not change the input field. If my observation is correct, then a solution can be to change and restore the value using `JQuery`. So, if I am right, something like the following may help:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var val = document.getElementById('fname');
      s = val.value;
      val.value = "4";
      val.value = s;
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <form action="/action_page.php">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="John" id="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am not sure if this is how it's done though.